# How can a script ask me questions?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am using this script to analyse data:

```
#!/bin/bash
in=/autofs/cluster/transcend/mega/scripts/
insub=/autofs/cluster/transcend/mega/dtn/20141015/123
out=/autofs/cluster/transcend/mega/scripts/1256

for i in $(cat $in/list_subjects.txt); do
echo "$i" 
mkdir ${insub}/${i}/file.nii.gz -k ${insub}/${i}/rh.nii.gz -M 

wait
done
```

How can this script ask me at the begining of it is work to confirm or change the paths in (in, insub and out)?

Comment: take a look on the Expect tool.
http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @vfbsilva This is a shell script. There is no need to switch to using a different programming language (tcl/expect), just use `read`!

Comment: @Celada the op edited the question... I did not have that info before hand.

Comment: oh, I see, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  And play around with it a bit.

```
echo -n "Press enter to use \"$in\" or enter a new value: "
read userInput
if [[ -n "$userInput" ]]
then
    in=$userInput
fi
echo ... I will use $in.
```

Error-checking (`test -d`, etc.) is up to you....

`read` is a bash builtin, so you can get help for it with the command `help read` (watch out, because you'll probably get results for both `read` and `readarray`, so be careful which help text you're *read*ing).  Reading the help will show you additional options, like the ones @Costas suggests using:

```
read -i $in -p "Press enter to use \"$in\" or enter a new value: " in
```

Comment: In the case `read -i $in -p "Accept by Enter or change to new value: "` is more readable

Comment: @drewbenn. Thanks!! it is working perfectly. Do I need to repeat all this code to choose many paths?